# How to show saved card page in stripe checkout-one-time-payments

Tags: java, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using checkout-one-time-payments for stripe for subscription and one time payments.This is the demo link from stripe  https://70p1h.sse.codesandbox.io/.

I am able to successfully collect payments for one time and subscription products . What I want to do now is to show a page that shows all the saved cards for the particular user if user has already made payment from stripe and then if user selects the pre saved card ,I want to move the customer direct to payment confirmation or failure. Dont want the user to re enter the card details and other info

I am using following code in backend for java

```
SessionCreateParams.Builder builder = new SessionCreateParams.Builder()

                

                .setSuccessUrl(createcheckoutSessionRequest.getSuccessUrl() + "?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}").setCancelUrl(createcheckoutSessionRequest.getFailureUrl())
                .addPaymentMethodType(PaymentMethodType.CARD)
                .setMode(product.getIsSubscriptionProduct() ? SessionCreateParams.Mode.SUBSCRIPTION
                        : SessionCreateParams.Mode.PAYMENT)
```

I am quite confused with all these docs ,I am not able to find the actual scenario in docs ,any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using a customer's saved cards is not something that is currently supported by Checkout.

If you want to build this functionality yourself you'd have to do the following:

- Retrieve all of a Customer's Payment Methods using the Stripe API (https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list).
- Once a Payment Method has been selected, use it along with the Customer ID to create a Payment Intent (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#web-create-payment-intent-off-session) or a Subscription (https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create).
- Depending on the status of payment, redirect to your own success or failure page.

Comment: any way to pass the saved payment method directly to session object?

Comment: No, that is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Stripe now supports using a customer's saved cards in Checkout.

This feature is automatically enabled in Checkout unless the 'Link with Stripe' feature is disabled in Stripe [Settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/checkout). You may find more information about this in the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/customization).

> Is there any way to pass the saved payment method directly to session object?

Yes. Pass a Customer object with an attached card payment method to a Checkout Session, and Checkout will prefill that customer’s previously saved card details so they can complete the payment with a 1-click checkout experience. You can read more about this in the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#handling-existing-customers).

Source: Stripe support